# PHP: Elegant Way to foreach Over a Subarray of an Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an associative array of arrays. The associative array of arrays does not always contain the same sub-arrays. I would like to loop through a particular sub-array if it exists. Is there a more elegant way to do the following code:

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'fizzy_drinks', $drinks ) ) {

    foreach ( $drinks['fizzy_drinks'] as $fizzy_drink ) {

        // do something with $fizzy_drink
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how I would do it. Simple yet effective. This question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. I think your solution is quite elegant, and readable.
I would do:

```
if (array_key_exists('fizzy_drinks', $drinks) && is_array($drinks['fizzy_drinks'])) {
    foreach ($drinks['fizzy_drinks'] as $fizzy_drink ) {
        // do something with $fizzy_drink
    }
}
```

Always nice to check if the value you try to use `foreach` on really is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, this is as much elegant as it gets:

```
if (isset($drinks['fizzy_drinks'])) {
    foreach ( $drinks['fizzy_drinks'] as $fizzy_drink ) {
        // do something with $fizzy_drink
    }
}
```

If you omit the isset you will get a notice if fizzy_drinks is not set, and a warning if $drinks is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer to use [is_array](https://www.php.net/is_array):

```
if(is_array($drinks['fizzy_drinks'])) {
  foreach ($drinks['fizzy_drinks'] as $fizzy_drink) {
    // do something with $fizzy_drink
  }
}
```

Comment: Works but you still get the damn notice thingy if $drinks doesn't have a 'fizzy_drinks' entry

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if (! empty($drinks['fizzy_drinks']) && is_array($drinks['fizzy_drinks'])) {
    foreach ($drinks['fizzy_drinks'] as $fizzy_drink) {
        // do something with $fizzy_drink
    }
}
```

no warnings, no notices